# Angular Material md-select default selected value

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular 2 with [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/component/select). Looking at the documentation, I am trying to get the select to have a default value as oppose to an empty place holder.

I have tried the following two options and both of them does not set a default value

```
<md-select selected="1">
  <md-option value="1" >One</md-option>
  <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
</md-select>

<md-select>
  <md-option value="1" selected="true">One</md-option>
  <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
</md-select>
```

I looked at all the documentations and the examples, none of them helped.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <mat-option value="1">One</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="2">Two</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Component:**

selectedOption = '1';

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhzugq)

---

**Edit #1:**

Since [**Material2.0.0#beta10**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta10-d%C3%A9coupage-panjandrum-2017-08-29) (specifically [**this PR**](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/5871)) you can *select* a value using the `value` *property* of `MatSelect`:

```
<mat-select [value]="selectedOption">
  <mat-option value="1">One</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="2">Two</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Component:**

selectedOption = '1';

Note that you can also use it with **two-way data binding -> [(value)]**.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhzugq-jhdlol)

Comment: That works. How did you find this is the way of doing it? Nowhere in the documentation mentioned this

Comment: It's a basic thing in Angular. Angular Material site/api/docs are still under construction, it's still on beta.

Comment: Can you look at the Angular Material documentation. For the md-option, there is a property of selected and a method select(). Wouldnt it make sense to do something like md-option selected="true" like a normal html dropdown?

Comment: Is there a property for md-option to make it default?

Comment: This is not working for me ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54168796/mat-select-not-showing-initially-selected-item)) - any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nice, they should really update material angular docs to say how to set the default value. Sure it's standard angular stuff, but people don't know if there is a custom API from the material angular component that they should use instead... and some people don't know the Angular way to set default form values still.

Answer (score 8):

```html
 <mat-select [value]="0" >
```

We can easily do it using  setting value to default value

Comment: Keep in mind that if you need to get the value after a new option is selected, use the Banana-in-a-Box method for receiving the event which will update the value: `<mat-select [(value)]="selectedValue" >`. Then just initialize `selectedValue` in your component and you can listen to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
<mat-select formControlName="timezone" required [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of array" [value]="item.value">{{item.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

for correct working need binding of value `[value]` or it don't work

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) you can do by the following way.

**Option:1**

```
<md-select value={{ defaultValue }}>
  <md-option value="{{ defaultValue }}">{{defaultValue}}</md-option>
  <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
  <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
  <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
</md-select>
```

**Option:2**

```
<md-select value="None">
  <md-option value="None">None</md-option>
  <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
  <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
  <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
</md-select>
```

It must any value of select dropdown. Else it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reactive Forms, you can do it this way:

In your template:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Sexo</mat-label>
   <mat-select [formControlName]="'sex'" #sexField>
      <mat-option value="2">Masculino</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="1">Femenino</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="3">Otro</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in your component:

```
form: FormGroup;
 
constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  

    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({        
        sex: ['2'], // set default option           
    });

     
    if (weAreEditing) {
        this.form.controls['sex'].setValue(edit.sex.id + ''); // set the option that you want
    }

}
```