# mat-select not showing initially selected item

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using `<mat-select-trigger>` in order to display selected items - in this case payment methods:

```xml
<div style="padding-top: 24px;">
  <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
    <mat-select placeholder="Zahlungsmethode" [(value)]="selectedPaymentMethod">

      <mat-select-trigger>
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
          <img [src]="selectedPaymentMethod.imageUrl" style="align-self: center; margin: 0 8px;">
          <span>{{selectedPaymentMethod.displayText}}</span>
        </div>
      </mat-select-trigger>

      <mat-option *ngFor="let pm of paymentMethods" [value]="pm">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
          <img [src]="pm.imageUrl" style="align-self: center; margin: 0 8px;">
          <span>{{pm.displayText}}</span>
        </div>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

My problem is that the initial value seems not to be reflected by the `mat-select` and I don't understand why.

In the `constructor` I am initializing `this.selectedPaymentMethod` to

```js
if (this.currentSubscription != null) {
  this.paymentMethod = data.currentSubscription.paymentMethod;
  this.selectedPaymentMethod = this.paymentMethod;
}
```

But it is simply not displayed. I've also tried to used `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(value)]`  but none of them works.

What am I doing wrong here?

As far as I can tell I am doing it like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clftid?file=app/select-value-binding-example.ts) (Stackblitz) but for some reason it's just not working here.

Comment: what is selectedPaymentMethod value? and what is paymentMethods?

Comment: @FatemeFazli It's  just an object with a `displayTest` and `imageUrl` property. It's not really important what it is. The items in the dropdown list are displayed correctly. As far as I can see I am doing it [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clftid?file=app/select-value-binding-example.ts) but it's just not working for some reason.

Comment: i think the selected item should be an item of your array.

Comment: @FatemeFazli Holy .... you are right. Why on earth does it have to be an item from the list, and if so, why does it not complain about the fact that I am doing something wrong. Well, thanks to you. If you want to provide an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why but the selected item should be an item of your array for example:

```js
this.selectedPaymentMethod = this.paymentMethods[0];
```

Comment: I find that the type of [(value)] variable needs to match the types stored by the selector, which may prefer strings. I had a selector bound to a number (5), and failing to set the default unless the bound variable contained a string ("5").