# How can I make an option default selected?

Tags: angular

Hi I am having an select box in my angular ui . I am populating it with some values when the component loads . I want to make the first item selected by default, however it not happening. not sure what is wrong with my code.

CdrMessageStatus

```
export enum CdrMessageStatus {
  ENROUTE = 'ENROUTE',
  DELIVERED = 'DELIVERED',
  EXPIRED = 'EXPIRED',
  UNDELIVERABLE = 'UNDELIVERABLE'
}
```

MessageHistoryComponent

```
export class MessageHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

 cdrStatuses = CdrMessageStatus;
 cdrStatusKeys: any[];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      range: [ [ ], Validators.required],
      cdrStatus: [],
      msisdn:[''],
      campaign: [],
      inventory: [],
      flight: []
     }
    );

    combineLatest(this.campaignsService.getStatuses(),this.authenticationService.currentUser$, of(this.authenticationService.authority),
                      this.flightsService.getStatuses()
                  ).subscribe(([campaignStatuses,user,authority,flightStatuses]) => {

              this.cdrStatusKeys = Object.keys(this.cdrStatuses);

}

}
```

message-history.component.html

```
  <div class="col-2">
      <select class="custom-select" formControlName="cdrStatus">
        <option [value]="" [selected]="selected" disabled>{{ 'LABELS.CDR_STATUS' | translate }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let key of cdrStatusKeys" [value]="key"> {{ cdrStatuses[key] }} </option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

also attaching a screenshot below
[image]

I can see the values populated.
   'ENROUTE','DELIVERED','EXPIRED','UNDELIVERABLE'
however i want to select the item by default

```
  <option [value]="" [selected]="selected" disabled>{{ 'LABELS.CDR_STATUS' | translate }}</option>
```

appreciate any help

Comment: this.formGroup.get('cdrStatus').setValue(object);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that the default option needs a value, without it, it doesn't show as a default option:

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="cdrStatus">
        <option [value]="null" [selected]="selected" disabled>{{ 'LABELS.CDR_STATUS' | translate }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let key of cdrStatusKeys" [value]="key"> {{ cdrStatuses[key] }} </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you have value = ""

```
<option [value]=""
```

You can set this to the first value. Hard coded.

```
<option [value] ='ENROUTE'
```

If you want dynamic:

Check this out: [Angular Material md-select default selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148392/angular-material-md-select-default-selected-value)

You can use two-way data binding:

```
this.selectedOption = '1';
```

HTML:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <mat-option value="1">One</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="2">Two</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: hi this is not what i want . i want to set this as default  <option [value]="" [selected]="selected" disabled>{{ 'LABELS.CDR_STATUS' | translate }}</option>

Answer (score 2):

Set the first value for the Select element in the TS:

```
this.formGroup.get('cdrStatus').setValue(object);
```