# pre selected dropdown in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

hi i using the angular material in angular 8 .

i need to pre-selected `option` in dropdwown .

i using this code :

```
<mat-select *ngIf="justImage==true">
    <mat-option selected (click)="setExtention('Picture',i)">
    {{ 'ENUM.FILE_TYPE.Picture' | translate }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

but it not selected in dropdown and disable that . it be disable but it not show selected items in dropdown .

how can i solve this problem ????

Comment: refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148392/angular-material-md-select-default-selected-value or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650790/set-default-option-in-mat-select

Comment: #1 Use `ng-container` for `if` condition.  #2 Remove `selected` attribute from `mat-option` tag.  #3 Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333171/angular-material-mat-select-not-selecting-default or mentioned by @ram12393

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333171/angular-material-mat-select-not-selecting-default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ts file,

```
let options = ['Upcoming', 'Consulted', 'Cancelled'];
let status = 'Consulted';
```

In your template,

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="status" id="status">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In the ngModel, status variable undergoes **two-way binding**. So, this will do the job. **Consulted** option will be selected by default.

Answer (score 2):

Although, answer is already accepted, but I want to give solution to this problem if you do not want to use [(ngModel)] two way data binding and want to break it down. Complete working example can be founded in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khxs5y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In your HTML File we use [value] as default value setters.

```
<mat-select [value]="defaultSelectedOption" id="status" (selectionChange)="onChange($event)">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
       {{food.viewValue}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<br> <br> <div>
              <span> Default selected and changable value is :<strong> {{defaultSelectedOption}}</strong> </span>
          </div>
```

Class file is..

```
defaultSelectedOption = '';
foods: Food[] = [
       {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
       {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
       {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
];
ngOnInit(){
     this.defaultSelectedOption = this.foods[1].value;
} 
onChange(eventValue){
     this.defaultSelectedOption= eventValue.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [working Examlpe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-41c1gm?file=app/select-form-example.html)

```
 ngOnInit()
 {
     this.selectedValue=this.clients[0];
 }
```

html

```
<mat-select [disabled]="true" placeholder="Clients" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food" (change)="changeClient($event.value)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client">
    {{client.clientName}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```